# aws cloudfront streaming distribution 502s

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I'm getting 502 errors setting up a streaming cloudfront distribution, and can't find anything online about setup issues, was wondering if anybody had had any experience of this?

My distribution and s3 bucket have both been setup about an hour, and my distribution is marked as Deployed in AWS Console. I can read files directly from the S3 bucket fine, but I get 502s when I try to access anything via the distribution. I'm doing this via a browser just to test everything's working before carrying on with my project. I've now also set up a non-streaming distribution on the same bucket and that works correctly, but I really want the streaming to work.

Anything I'm missing here? Any help / guidance appreciated. Thank you!